# Mail client sender picure

Tags: email, dns, icons, meta, favicon

UPDATE: closing and moving to https://superuser.com/q/1491110/129302

I am asking this on Stackoverflow because I honestly have no idea about the actual implementation , so depending on answer, I will move it later.

The question is: why email client, for example, Windows Mail, displays icons (sender pictures) from several companies.

[image]

As you can see, Microsoft, Tubmlr, Paypal provides pictures.
As well as Godaddy, Amazon, Github, Quora, Medium, Meetup and others.
But the majority of business senders has no sender pictures.

How sender pictures are implemented?

**What I've tried already:**

Let's pretend, I own hello@example.com

1. Added hello@example.com to Gravatar and uploaded custom icon.
2. Created Google Account for hello@example.com and changed account picture.
3. Added favicon.ico to example.com
4. Added webmanifest with multiple icon sizes to example.com
5. Tried multiple link tags in / of example.com
6. Configured DNS server to include all required records (SPF/TXT/DMARC/DKIM) for BIMI.

No luck yet. Are they hardcoded in email client?
That would be strange, because why Quora is hardcoded in, while Yahoo is not, so I may reject this theory.

I have also noticed, that sender picture depends on the full email address: there is a picture in email from no-reply-aws@amazon.com, but there is no in email from aws-marketing-email-replies@amazon.com

How it is done?

Comment: Did you look at email headers? An "avatar" image can also be encoded there. Double check with any other email clients as it may be hardcoded in the client and not be a property really of the email or associated domain. Also as for BIMI you need to have DMARC already, see https://blog.mxtoolbox.com/2019/07/03/bimi-record-what-is-it-how-does-it-add-to-dmarc/. And it is easy to see from your list used as example above, multiple companies displayed do not have a BIMI record in the DNS.

Comment: Also I do not think that "How sender pictures are implemented?" is really on topic here on a programming website. You are probably more a good fit on [su], but double check their help section.

Comment: Patrick, yes, your mentioned mxtoolbox has BIMI validator https://mxtoolbox.com/bimi.aspx and I've already checked configuration. Probably Window Mail does not use BIMI at all. I was just a try.

Comment: A good try indeed, but I fear Windows Mail probably uses some internal proprietary mechanisms. Looking at the raw emails and what exists in headers, as well as testing in other mail clients (web based or standalone) would be my next two steps if I were to investigate this.

Comment: Regarding, SuperUser, probably you are right, but I am not sure yet that it's a programming related question, if the implementation is email header or some special meta tag.